# How to use reg expression as a variable

Tags: ksh, glob

I'm using ksh and I have a directory full of .csv and .CSV files. I want to list all csv files, both capital and lowercase endings. So I type:

```
ls *@(CSV|csv)
```

and that lists all the files.

But if I set the the regular expression as a variable like so:

```
REGEXP="*@(CSV|csv)"
ls $REGEXP
```

I get the error

```
ls: cannot access *@(CSV|csv): No such file or directory
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference between these two commands and how to fix it so that I can use the variable in place of writing out the regex?

Comment: Maybe use the `nocaseglob` shell option instead?

Comment: The other choice is `eval ls $pattern`. I'm not sure why it's not expanding. According the the manual it should.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really regex but globbing as you indicate in the [glob] tag.

With globbing use this:

```
$ ls *.[Cc][Ss][Vv]
a.csv  a.CSV  b.csv  b.CSV
$ GLOB=*.[Cc][Ss][Vv]
$ ls $GLOB
a.csv  a.CSV  b.csv  b.CSV
```